# How to call clicklistener of an item's textview inside a recyclerview outside the adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview inside an activity. I have some View inside each item. Suppose a textview, I am implementing a click listener on that particular view.

However, there is a case where i have to call the clicklistener of a particular position of that textview.

Since there is no function to call the onclick where i can pass the position.

I thought holder.itemview.callonclick() would work. But it is not working.

is there any way to call the itemview's textview of a particular position of a recyclerview.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom click listener using interface like below.

```
public interface ClickInterface {
public void recyclerviewOnItemClick(int position);
```

}

make sure you implement this interface to class where you want your code to be executed and implement it's method.Then you can pass this listerer's refrence to adapter like this.

```
TestAdapter adapetr = new TestAdapter (this);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In adapter :

```
private ClickInterface clickInterface;
public TestAdapter (ClickInterface clickInterface) {
    this.clickInterface = clickInterface;
}

viewHolder.txtview.setOnClickListener(v -> 
clickInterface.recyclerviewOnItemClick(position));
```

-You will get implemented method call when textview is being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in Holder class,

```
  mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             if (getAdapterPosition()== YOUR_POS)
             {
               code..
             }
            }
        });
```

or in onBindViewHolder ,`

```
if(i==YOUR_POS){ holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               code..

            }
        });}
```